# a loop in the server which reads all the client sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, connection

Suppose that i have a class ServerReader which is a Thread that runs all the time. the ServerReader have a loop that reads all the messages from all client in a way like this:

```
while(true) {
    for(Socket socket: sockets_arraylist) {
        ObjectInputStream object_stream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        String str = (String) object_stream.readObject();
        System.out.println("message from client: " + str);
        object_stream.close();
    }
}
```

As i understand, when the loop encounter readObject() method, the Thread is going to sleep until the client actually sending an object.
So imagine this scenerio:
the ArrayList "sockets_arraylist" contains 2 sockets. The second socket on the list, which belongs to client number 2 waiting to recieve a message. Client number 2 sending this message and wait for the server to read it. But there is a problem: the loop above stuck at readObject() method that waits for the message from client 1. so until client 1 will not send his message to the server, client`s 2 message will not be read.

Do i need to make on the server a separete thread for each client? or there is another solution?

Comment: Don't create a new `ObjectInputStream` every time you want to read a socket. Use the same one for the life of the socket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1) Use a separate thread for each client.

2) Use asynchronous IO using [`java.nio`](https://blogs.oracle.com/slc/entry/javanio_vs_javaio) - in this case you'd probably want [`SocketChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html).

Using a separate thread for each client is *likely* to be conceptually simpler, although it does mean you need to consider race conditions more carefully. Using NIO *may* be more scalable (different benchmarks show different results, and it may well depend on your OS as well, in terms of how costly threads and scheduling are.)